Flutter Hero Animation path override
I'm building an app with a Hero animation that transitions from a home screen to a second screen. Here's a simplified version of my code:
// A single tile, placed in a grid
class BeverageTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Beverage beverage;

  const BeverageTile({
    super.key,
    required this.beverage,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String price = beverage.price == null ? 'Free' : '\$${beverage.price}';

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
        FadePageRoute(
          page: BeverageSelectionScreen(beverage: beverage),
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2),
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 12.0,
                      vertical: 6.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      price,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 16.0,
                  left: 16.0,
                  right: 16.0,
                ),
                // SETUP OF THE HERO
                child: Hero(
                  createRectTween: (begin, end) {
                    return RectTween(begin: begin, end: end);
                  },
                  tag: 'beverage_${beverage.name}',
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    beverage.imagePath,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 16.0,
                horizontal: 8.0,
              ),
              child: Text(
                beverage.name,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Second screen
class BeverageSelectionScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Beverage beverage;

  const BeverageSelectionScreen({super.key, required this.beverage});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFF1a1718),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(72.0),
        child: Hero(
          tag: 'beverage_${beverage.name}',
          child: SvgPicture.asset(
            beverage.imagePath,
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I've also implemented a custom PageRouteBuilder to handle the transition animation between pages. The Hero animation works as expected, but the image currently follows a curved path, which is the default behavior according to the Material Design motion spec.
Question: How can I customize the path of the Hero animation so that the image moves along a linear path instead of the default curved trajectory?

By default, Hero uses MaterialRectArcTween, which creates a curved animation path. To make the hero follow a linear path, use a RectTween in the createRectTween property:
createRectTween: (begin, end) => RectTween(begin: begin, end: end),

Important:
Make sure to override createRectTween in both Hero widgets (on both pages) to ensure that the reverse animation is linear as well.

Full example:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() {
  // Slow down the animation to better see the Hero flight.
  timeDilation = 15.0;

  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: HeroLinearPathExample(),
    ),
  );
}

class HeroLinearPathExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const HeroLinearPathExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Linear Hero Animation Example'),
      ),
      body: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => const SecondPage(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'hero-tag',
            createRectTween: (begin, end) {
              // Enforce a linear animation
              return RectTween(begin: begin, end: end);
            },
            child: const FlutterLogo(size: 100),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second Page'),
      ),
      body: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        child: Hero(
          tag: 'hero-tag',
          createRectTween: (begin, end) {
            // Enforce a linear animation for the reverse transition
            return RectTween(begin: begin, end: end);
          },
          child: const FlutterLogo(size: 100),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Thank you! that fixed it for me! I forget to add the second createRectTween in the hero widget.

If you want to have a little bit more control over the curve of the Hero liniear path, create a new class that extends RectTween:
class CurveRectTween extends RectTween{
  CurveRectTween({
    super.begin,
    super.end,
    required this.curve,
  });

  final Curve curve;

  @override
  Rect lerp(double t) {
    return super.lerp(curve.transform(t));
  }
}

Hero(
  createRectTween: (Rect? begin, Rect? end) {
    return CurveRectTween(begin: begin, end: end, curve: Curves.easeInCirc);
  },
  tag: 'beverage_${beverage.name}',
  child: SvgPicture.asset(beverage.imagePath.toString(),
      fit: BoxFit.contain),
)

